# how to use javascript to validate xml against schema in firefox?

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd, activexobject

I can do this in IE using ActiveXObject, however mozilla doesn't support ActiveXObject. Is there any way I can use JS to validate an XML against an XSD schema in firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no other browser has a Schema validator built-in. You would have to write your own in JavaScript, if you really wanted to run a validator in the browser. (It's a pretty unusual thing to want to do; usually this kind of thing is strictly server-side.)